# Program gets 101 numbers instead of 100

Tags: c

This is a simple C program which gets 100 numbers from user and counts even and odd numbers.
Problem is that it gets 101 numbers instead of 100. i checked it twice and i can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int i;
    int numbers[101];
    int even = 0, odd = 0;


    printf("%s", "Enter 100 numbers:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 101; i++) {

        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);

        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)
            even++;
        else
            odd++;

        printf("even is %d odd is %d\n", even, odd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change the 101 to 100 in the `for` loop

Comment: In `for (i=0; i<101; i++)` i can have the value 0 and the value 100. That is a total of 101 values. If 100 is included you must start at 1.

Comment: Your for loop counts from 0 to 100. That's 101 numbers.

Comment: Well, you're using 101 as your array size, and 0-100 (which is 101 numbers) in your loop. Why would you expect to get less than 101 numbers?

Comment: this line: 'for (i = 0; i < 101; i++) {' shows a range from 0 through 100.  That is 101 entries.  suggest changing that line to: 'for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {'

Comment: This question is almost a definition of Obi Wan errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you start counting from zero, you will count an extra number.

0 ... 1   => this is 2 numbers

0... 100  => this is 101 numbers

So count from 1 to 100, or from 0 to 99 - e.g.

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
```

Answer (score 10):

Just change this:

```
int numbers[101];
```

to:

```
int numbers[100];
```

and this:

```
for (i=0; i<101; i++)
```

to:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
```

Also so you wouldn't have to change this number in 2 places you could define a constant like this:

```
#define SIZE 100
```

and then you can use the constant instead(`int numbers[SIZE];`, `for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)`)!